# C++ - Feasibility and performance of passing NULL vs. allocating empty std::set to pass to method

Tags: c++, performance

I'm doing some performance tuning work. Basically, I have found a potential bottleneck in our code base and thinking of the best solution for it. I will try to keep this question as simple as possible. Basically, I have a method that will work with a set of double values (std::set). So the method signature looks something like:

```
void MyClass::CalculateStuff(const std::set<double> & mySet);
```

There are several places in the code that call this method. Only a few of these places need to work with this set while others don't care about the set. I suppose I could create another version of this method that includes this set and modify the existing one to use an empty set. However, this would create some overhead for the places that don't care about the set (because they would have to make additional method calls). So the other option I thought of was using a pointer to a set argument instead, like so:

```
void MyClass::CalculateStuff(const std::set<double> * pMySet);
```

The validity of the pointer would determine whether we want to use the set or not (i.e. passing NULL pointer for the set argument means that we do no work associated with the set). This would be faster but obviously not clean from an interface perspective. I suppose I could heavily comment the code.

What do you think should be done? This is probably not a huge deal but it got me thinking about how far you should go to make your code faster (if performance is very important in an application) vs. making sure the code is still clean and manageable. Where should the line be drawn in this case?

Comment: It seems like overloading is what you want. I don't understand what you mean when you say *"However, this would create some overhead for the places that don't care about the set "*.

Comment: `boost::optional` is pretty much made for an optional argument, works better than a `const T*`.

Comment: Interesting. When you say "works better", do you mean in terms of cleanliness or performance?

Answer (score 0):

well i do games programming. and for me. i only worry about potential bottlenecks when the game starts lagging then i profile etc.

passing in by pointer will be more memory efficent as a pointer to a object is only 4bytes. but i do suggest when you pass it null. that you use `nullptr` as thats the current standard to define a null pointer rather then `NULL` or `0`.

im guessing you are passing in a set to calculate something with the class's set. in which case maybe overloading operators would be the best option for you?

Comment: Got it. The nature of the task I am working on is about shaving time off at the millisecond level. I have found a way to get this method to only take 20 ms. as opposed to 40 ms. in some contexts (this is very critical code that must run extremely fast in our application). However, in order to accomplish this, I need to pass in this new set argument I have introduced. I am just trying to balance performance with some level of cleanliness as well.

Comment: have you considered converting it to assembly calls to perform your operation? because that is the next step for big millisecond gains once you run out of options in c/c++

Comment: Zanven, I know that our team has talked about it before. It's not my decision to go down that path anyway. :P

Comment: well i personally havent done assembly but my friend did it for his math library. its apparently not hard. just hard to find the most efficent way to do it. best of luck :P.